# Select HTML tags that have one or more specific attributes with bs4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, attr

I want to use use `soup.find_all` to find all HTML tags that have `id` or `name` attributes.

The following code works for the id attribute:

```
for tag in soup.find_all(attrs={"id": True}):
```

However, the following code with two attributes doesn't:

```
for tag in soup.find_all(attrs={"id":True, "name":True}):
```

Is it possible to do a Boolean search with bs4 that will find all tags that have one of two specific attributes (or both attributes) or will I have to search for each attribute separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
soup.find_all(lambda element: 'name' in element.attrs or 'id' in element.attrs)
```

We use `lambda` to access the element inside `find_all`. And then, we use the `in` operator to check if `element.attrs` (it's a dictionary) has key `name` **or** `id`.